# Which version of Zend Framework 1 is compatible with PHP7?

Tags: zend-framework, php-7

After which version Zend Framework become compatible with PHP7?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

according to zf1's blog you, Zend seems to be compatible with php7 since version 1.12.12 (it's a version from april 2015).
https://framework.zend.com/changelog/1.12.12

You should be able to run php7 and zf1 with the stable version of zf1.

Hope this helped