# Upgrading PHP from 5.3 to 7.0 on Zend Framework

Tags: zend-framework

I'm joining a new team. Their current setup is on the Zend Framework 2.3.0 running on PHP 5.3.10. One of their complaints is speed so I'd like to switch gears to PHP 7.0.X Is this possible to do safely? If I upgrade to 7.0.X would I break anything within the Zend framework?

Comment: I don't think there will be any problem. Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35500872/which-version-of-zend-framework-1-is-compatible-with-php7

Comment: Ah great. Reason I even asked is because I know PhpBB requires > 5.3.x && < 5.x.x

Comment: On zf website they never really mention anything about incompatibilities so I assume it's safe to use PHP7. Besides PHP7 are mostly enhancements, zf as the leading framework should have supported it for long.